# using xargs to unzip multiple files

Tags: linux, xargs, rar

I'm trying to unrar a tonne of files in a directory using xargs...

having little luck with this command:

```
find /home/jchristian/bfdata/2014/*.rar -print0 | xargs -0r unrar x
```

gives the following output:

```
UNRAR 5.00 beta 3 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2013 Alexander Roshal
Extracting from /home/jchristian/bfdata/2014/bfinf_horse_140106to140112_140115120001.rar

No files to extract
```

Yes, When I run unrar with that file outputted above - It extracts gracefully...

```
unrar x     /home/jchristian/bfdata/2014/bfinf_horse_140106to140112_140115120001.rar

UNRAR 5.00 beta 3 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2013 Alexander Roshal


Extracting from   /home/jchristian/bfdata/2014/bfinf_horse_140106to140112_140115120001.rar

Extracting  bfinf_horse_140106to140112_140115120001.csv               OK 
All OK
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the option `-t` additionally to `xargs` and put its output here?

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
find /home/jchristian/bfdata/2014/ -name *.rar | xargs -n 1 unrar x
```

`find` need a path **and** an expression, so

```
find /home/jchristian/bfdata/2014/*.rar -print0
```

will return nothing

Comment: That outputs:    find /home/jchristian/bfdata/2014/ -name *.rar | xargs -n 1 unrar x
    find: paths must precede expression:     bfinf_horse_140113to140119_140122120001.rar
    Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

    UNRAR 5.00 beta 3 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2013 Alexander Roshal

    Usage:     unrar <command> -<switch 1> -<switch N> <archive> <files...>
                   <@listfiles...> <path_to_extract\>

Comment: but this worked....

    find /home/jchristian/bfdata/2014/*.rar | xargs -n 1 unrar x

Comment: hmm, your `find` is different than mine (OSX/Freebsd)  :D

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the xargs step by using `find -exec`

```
find /home/jchristian/bfdata/2014 -name \*.rar -exec unrar x {} \;
```

You need e or x after unrar